# discontinuity of $\sin \frac {1}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have this function:
$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin \frac {1}{x} & x \ne 0\\
0 & x = 0\end{cases}$

I have to establish if $f(x)$ is continuous or discontinuous somewhere and, in this last case, the kind of discontinuity.

$f(0)=0$ and $\not\exists \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} sin \frac {1}{x}$
$x=0$ is a point of discontinuity of third kind.
Is it right?

Comment: What is the third kind of discontinuity?

Comment: You're correct, although your notation is a bit funky.

Comment: @Bernard An oscillatory discontinuity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what of the third kind means but I can show you it is discontinuous another way. A function is continuous if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) = f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n)$ for convergent sequences $a_n$ in the domain of $f$.

Let's consider $b_n = \frac{1}{\pi n}$. It is obvious that the sequence converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. If $f$ was continuous then we would have,

$$0 =f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(b_n)$$

However, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(b_n)$ does not exist since it goes $0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1,\ldots$